# Angular can't use fontawesome in dynamic component

Tags: angular

I used this [post](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e) to load dynamically some components

```
 import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

 const template =`
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button (click)="play()" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info">
        <fa-icon icon="play"></fa-icon>
      </button>

    </div>`;
    const tmpCmp = Component({template: template})(class {

    });
    const tmpModule = NgModule({
      imports: [CommonModule,FontAwesomeModule],
      declarations: [tmpCmp]
    })(class {
    });

    this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
        .then((factories) => {
            const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
            const cmpRef = f.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);
            cmpRef.instance.name = 'B component';
            this._container.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
        })
```

When the template is loaded with fa-icon nothing is displayed and no error are returned.

Comment: Where is the template for fa-icon?  Typically when using FA on a standard html tag you add a class "fa fa-iconName".  This is typically on a span / i tag: <span class="fa fa-plane"></span>.  Have you done that for your fa-icon definition?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add an fa class dynamically, I would use [ngClass] to show a specific fa icon because you can use interpolation:

In your component:

```
public faIcon:string="fa-plane"
```

I have hardcoded an fa-icon name here, but you can set it however you want.

in your template:

```
<span class="fa" [ngClass]="{faIcon}}></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Icon faPlay import from package "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"

```
import { faPlay} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
```

In dynamic template:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faPlay"></fa-icon>
```

Add to class public variable "faPlay":

```
const tmpCmp = Component({template: template})(class {
  faPlay = faPlay
});
```

Result:

```
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { faPlay} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

 const template =`
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button (click)="play()" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info">
        <fa-icon [icon]="faPlay"></fa-icon>
      </button>

    </div>`;
    const tmpCmp = Component({template: template})(class {
      faPlay = faPlay
    });
    const tmpModule = NgModule({
      imports: [CommonModule,FontAwesomeModule],
      declarations: [tmpCmp]
    })(class {
    });

    this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
        .then((factories) => {
            const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
            const cmpRef = f.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);
            cmpRef.instance.name = 'B component';
            this._container.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
        })
```